# How to Execute a command through electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder

I am trying to execute a command on the click of an element in the electron app.

The code is:

```
function displayadbinfo(command) {
    const childProcess = require('child_process');
    alert(childProcess.execSync(command).toString());
}
```

This code pops up an alert when I click on the app which is launched with `npm start`. However, after building the executable file, the command returns an empty response.

Answer (score 1):

`child_process.execSync` returns a buffer or a string rather than a stream, which could be causing an empty response. It waits for the child process to exit and tries to return all the buffered data at once. I suggest you to use [`child_process.spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options).

The difference is that `child_process.spawn` returns a `ChildProcess` object and `stdout` and `stderr` are accessible using streams rather than synchronously returned as a buffer. So, you'd be able to see the output correctly.

I am not sure if `electron-builder` or `electron-packager` might be causing issues.

You can find an article discussing the differences between `spawn ()` and `exec ()` [here on hacksparrow.com](https://www.hacksparrow.com/difference-between-spawn-and-exec-of-node-js-child_process.html)

Comment: I figured that when I execute after the package, it is not running the command in the HOME_PATH, which is causing issue. How do I get the user home path and then run the command within that home?I tried the libaries `fix_path` and `shell_path`, but though it returns the home, the command does not seem to run in there. I ll try the spawn

Comment: Try the electron method: `app.getPath('home')` to get the user's home directory. https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#appgetpathname